# How to add any custom image in Camera screen while capturing image?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, avcam

I want to add custom `UIImage` in **Camera Screen** while user capture the photo. Also i want that image in foreground of that captured image on the same position the image is added. 
[Here the demo image that explain what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1aTA.jpg).
To work around this i have try

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.sourceType = .Camera
picker.view.addSubView(imageView)
```

But using this code it will only add image not add image with the capture image

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Hi, I'm also trying similar stuff and wondering how you solve this issue.
I'm using AVFoundation and want to add some UI images to both in the camera screen and the captured photo & video. 

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Yuuu Sorry, I haven't found a proper solution for this one and not able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIImagePickerController`'s `cameraOverlayView` property to add  the `imageView` on top of the camera screen:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.delegate = self
picker.sourceType = .Camera
picker.cameraOverlayView = imageView

presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For adding the image to the foreground of the captured photo you can create an extension for `UIImage`:

```
extension UIImage {
  func imageWithOverlayImage(overlayImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size)

    self.drawInRect(imageRect)
    overlayImage.drawInRect(imageRect)

    let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return resultImage
  }
}
```

Then you can call it from the delegate method of the image picker:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
  let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
  finalImage = image.imageWithOverlayImage(overlayImage!)
  dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I have already try this, but it didn't work for me. Thanks for help.

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala Can you explain why this isn't working for you?

Comment: I have already try to merge two images before posting this question but id didn't work properly. And also i try your code but it also not merging two images properly.

Answer (score 0):

try putting Overlayview. add custom image to overlayview.

```
func openCamera(){

        let pickercontroller : UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickercontroller.delegate = self

        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){

            pickercontroller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        }
        else{
        }

        pickercontroller.editing = false
        pickercontroller.showsCameraControls = false
        let graphRect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0,pickercontroller.view.frame.size.width-20 ,pickercontroller.view.frame.size.height)

        let overlayView : UIView = UIView(frame: graphRect)
        overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
        overlayView.layer.opaque = false
        overlayView.opaque = false

        var maskLayer : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        overlayView.layer.mask = maskLayer
      }
```

Comment: I already try with overlay view, this will only add overlay view on camera screen what i want is that dress image merge with camera image at run time when picture is click.